# Check for duplicate values in column and then add Conditional Formatting when SUM > 8 in the corresponding rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I don't know if I formulated my question properly, I can't seem to figure out the logic for this problem by myself. I am working on a Resource Planner in Excel

The best way I know how to explain is to show it with a screenshot:

1. Check if hours worked per DAY is > 8, then apply conditional formatting to the last added number
   [image: NA]
2. Check if hours worked per WEEK is > 40, then apply conditional formatting to the last added number to indicate the exceeding hours

[image: NA]

So basically, the way I thought about it is: first I have to check for duplicate values in the 'Resource' column. Then I have to match those rows with the actual DAY column (for example Monday) and then sum the total hours each time. If the total exceeds 8, then apply conditional formatting to indicate an error.

And then do the same for a whole week when it exceeds 40 hours.

I am not that great with Excel or formulas, so I can't think of a way to combine several formulas to achieve my goal. I was thinking of a combination of an Array formula with maybe multiple IF statements? But I don't know where or how to even begin.

To find the duplicates I could use this formula?
=COUNTIF(A:A, A2)>1

But then how do I make sure that the corresponding rows are aware of which cells to use in the check for SUM > 8 per day? 
And then furthermore, how do I add the corresponding cells to check for SUM > 40 per week?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to change the spreadsheet slightly. For example to add a row with the actual dates in as 2020-01-22 , 2020-01-23, etc ? .It could be hidden. Also what is the significance of the colours in the header row ?

Comment: @CDP1802 The actual dates are underneath the Week headers (where it says 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.). They are just displayed as 'd' only, but the full dates are known in the cells themselves by Excel. The colours in the date headers are to indicate holiday dates and weekend days. 

The highlighted Person 2 is to indicate that a person could be assigned to multiple projects and thats why I need to make sure that one person cannot exceed 8 hours of work a day even if they are working on multiple projects.

Comment: I will post some demo code for the day check. Paste it into a blank workbook and run the creatTest. The week check is more complicated but the principle would be the same. I have put a message box in to show the sum calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For day limit you can try following formula:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW($E4),COLUMN(E$4),4)=ADDRESS(IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A4=$A$4:$A$14)*E$4:E$14)>8,MAX(IF(($A4=$A$1:$A$14),ROW(($A$1:$A$14))-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$14))+1)),1),COLUMN(E4),4)
```

It does exactly what you asked for.

[image]

But a week problem is more complicated, I can only offer solution with the last line highlighted if working hours exceeds 40.

```
=ADDRESS(ROW($E4),COLUMN(E$4),4)=ADDRESS(IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A4=$A$4:$A$14)*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4,5+(7*FLOOR.MATH(MAX(COLUMN(E1)-4)/7.000001)))&":" & ADDRESS(14,11+(7*FLOOR.MATH(MAX(COLUMN(E1)-4)/7.000001)))))>40,MAX(IF(($A4=$A$1:$A$14),ROW(($A$1:$A$14))-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$14))+1)),1),COLUMN(E4),4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the Worksheet_Change event to trigger a calculation using SUMIF for the column identied by the Target parameter. For the week calculation, set the range to use the 7 columns from the start of the week. It gets complicated if for example you enter 7 on one line, 2 on another (which gets highlighted) and then go back and change the 7 to 6. Here is a demo to explain further

```vb
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       Dim iCol, iRow As Long
       Dim dDate As Date, sPerson As String
       Dim sumDay

       ' determine person, week
       ' abort if outside data sheet
       iCol = Target.Column
       iRow = Target.Row
       If iRow < 5 Or iCol < 3 Then Exit Sub

       ' determine date, person , hours
       dDate = Cells(2, iRow)
       sPerson = Cells(iRow, 2).Value ' person in col B
       sumDay = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Columns(2).EntireColumn, Range("B" & iRow), Target.EntireColumn)

       ' summate
       MsgBox sPerson & vbCr & dDate & vbCr & "Hours = " & Target.Value & vbCr & "Total = " & sumDay

       ' colour check
       If sumDay > 8 Then
         Target.Interior.Color = vbYellow
       Else
         Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite
       End If

     End Sub

     Sub createTest()
        Dim cell As Range, i As Integer, dDate As Date
        dDate = "2020-01-06"

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
          .Cells.Clear
          For Each cell In Range("C2:L2")
             cell.Value = dDate
             cell.Offset(1, 0) = "=TEXT(" & cell.Address & ",""ddd"")"
             dDate = dDate + 1
             .Range("B4") = "Resource"

             ' records
             For i = 5 To 25
               Cells(i, 2) = "Person " & Int(5 * Rnd + 1)
             Next
          Next
        End With
        Columns("A:L").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Rows("3:3").Font.Bold = True
     End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried using VBA yet, but I'll have a look